# How to copy files in JAVA by bufferedInputStream and bufferedOutputStream?

Tags: java, eof, bufferedinputstream, bufferedoutputstream

I would like to use `bufferedInputStream` and `bufferedOutputStream` to copy large binary files from source file to destination file.

Here is my code:

```
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];        
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        int numBytes;
        while ((numBytes = bis.read(buffer))!= -1)
        {
            bos.write(buffer);
        }
        //bos.flush();
        //bos.write("\u001a");

        System.out.println(args[0]+ " is successfully copied to "+args[1]);

        bis.close();
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can successfully copy but then I use

```
cmp src dest
```

in the command line to compare two files. 
The error message

> cmp: EOF on files

appears. May I know where I was wrong?

Comment: data is there in file from which you are reading?? or any exception is coming??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the mistake:

```
bos.write(buffer);
```

You're writing out the *whole* buffer, even if you only read data into *part* of it. You should use:

```
bos.write(buffer, 0, numBytes);
```

I'd also suggest using try-with-resources if you're using Java 7 or later, or put the `close` calls in a `finally` block otherwise.

As Steffen notes, [`Files.copy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) is a simpler approach if that's available to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried bos.write(buffer, 0, numBytes). It works!

Comment: @BinbinTang: Whoops, yes - fixed in the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 try the `Files.copy(Path source, Path target)` method.

Comment: some additional information about copying files: http://www.journaldev.com/861/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java

Answer (score 2):

you need to close your `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream`

Also you can use FileChannel to copy like as follows

```
FileChannel from = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
FileChanngel to = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
to.transferFrom(from, 0, from.size());
from.close();
to.close();
```

Comment: That's copying a byte at a time though - very inefficient.

Comment: Yep, copy one byte per time is too inefficient.

Comment: @JonSkeet yep  modified,

Comment: I found that this didn't work when copying files larger (100GB) than the remaining free space on my C: drive (where the app is running).  I am currently trying to use `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` which appears to be working, but kinda slow.  Is there an even faster version of this answer that doesn't require space free on the C: drive?  Perhaps some version of the buffered streams?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from apatch-commons library

I think copyLarge fucntion it that you need

Comment: as stated in this article (http://www.journaldev.com/861/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java), the apache-commons is the slowest solution.